# Detecting an NSSlider value change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsslider

How do I wire up an action programmatically to my NSSlider to detect when the value changes?

I'm looking for the Cocoa equivalent of a UISlider that would be done with the following code.

```
[myUISlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd use the following code:

```
[slider setTarget:self];
[slider setAction:@selector(valueChanged:)];
```

That's it.

`NSSlider` uses an `NSSliderCell`, which is a custom subclass of [`NSActionCell`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSActionCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSActionCell); I'd look over that documentation for the target action mechanism in Cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

```
[slider setTarget:self];
[slider setContinuous:YES];
[slider setAction:@selector(valueChanged:)];

-(void)valueChanged:(NSSlider *)sender{ 

}
```